# Azure DNS remove NS records

Tags: azure, dns

We want to transfer a site from Azure AppServices to an external host because of cost.

The domain is managed through Azure. When I try to update the NS records, I can't remove the Azure ones, they're grayed out.

Do I have to delete the AppService first? I'd rather not have any downtime during this transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to update the NS records, I can't remove the Azure ones, they're grayed out.

*You can't **modify** or **Remove** the pre-populated **NS records** as per this [Microsoft Document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-operations-recordsets-cli#to-modify-ns-records-at-the-zone-apex)*

> You can add more name servers to this NS record set, to support cohosting domains with more than one DNS provider. You may also modify the TTL and metadata for this record set. However, you can't remove or modify the pre-populated Azure DNS name servers.

[image]

*Rather you can add new NS records if you require any*

*Here is the CLI command for adding another Name server to the NS record.*

```
az network dns record-set ns add-record --resource-group myresourcegroup --zone-name contoso.com --record-set-name "@" --nsdname ns1.myotherdnsprovider.com
```

Comment: Thanks. So I'm unable to use Azure for DNS without also using it for hosting.